# Point Density Distribution Using ggplot2 in r

Tags: r, maps, spatial

I would like to create a plot similar to the plot located in the following link at the top of the page:

http://internetcensus2012.bitbucket.org/images/worldmap_16to9_1600x900.png

I am using R3.3.1 on a Windows 7 system. I have two data frames. The first df contains lat long coordinates for IP addresses. The second df is a fortified shapefile of a world map. Both the points and the shapefile df have the same projection.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
g = ggplot()
g = g + geom_polygon(data = worldmap.df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
                     color = "gray10", size = 0.1, fill = "black")
g = g + geom_point(data = pointsData, aes(x = long, y = lat), 
                   color = "green", size = 0.1) 
g = g + theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
              panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
              panel.background = element_rect(fill = "black"))
```

This only maps my lat long points on top of my world map. I have experimented with `stat_density2d` and `stat_binhex` with no success. Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you provide the data to make the example reproducible?

Comment: Along with some data, can you alaso explain why "lat long points on top of my world map" is not what is desired?

Comment: whats the best way to upload the data?

Comment: Also, Ive revised the initial plotting code and gotten something closer to what I wanted, but am still a little confused. Should I post an answer to my question to allow for more space to attach data and the modified code?

Comment: I can try to clear up youre second comment. I often have lists of IP addresses ranging from a few thousand to a few million. After using the free maxmind database, I obtain lat/long coordinates for each IP. For IP lists over 100,000, I feel the best way to display the IP coordinates is to create a heat map similar to that found in the attached link in the initial question. I obtained something close by using "stat_bin_2d" and adjusting the bins and binwidth. However, ive seen several ways to use density distribution to do this and have confused myself